# Get the difference of Values between two records in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, records

I have a sqlite table with the following data,

```
 _Id       Mode         Reading
  1       Water           100
  2       Water           300
  5       Water           496
  6       Water           600
```

Now I want the difference of the values between records. For example,
 The difference b/w(column Reading) 100 and 300 is "200", 300 and 496 is "196" and 496 and 600 is "104".

I want the query result as,

```
 Reading
  200
  196
  104
```

How to get this done in sqlite? 
 can any one please help. I am very poor in sqlite.

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is the `Mode` column in any way related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the values from database using cursor and do something like :

```
   cursor.moveToNext();
   int prevVal = cursor.getInt(2);
   while(cursor.moveToNext())
   {
      int curVal= cursor.getInt(2);
      int reading = curVal-prevVal;
      prevVal=curVal;
   }
```

You may declare `reading` as an array and display it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks!! I need the query to perform in sqlite.

Comment: ok..then u may like to refer this : **http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial**